# Writing if statements in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the best in place gem installed. For a user profile it has an About Me section. It is setup to show the `about_me` attribute, however I want to add if statements to it.

For example if current_user has not filled out their about_me attribute then the box should read “Describe yourself here”. And if other users are viewing the page and that User did not fill out the about me section, it should read “USERNAME has not filled out their about me section yet”

I am not sure at how to add those two rules.

View:

```
  .testimonial_box
    = best_in_place @user, :about_me, :type => :text area
```

Updated code:

```
        .testimonial_box
          - if current_user == @user
            - if @user.about_me
              = best_in_place @user, :about_me, :type => :textarea
            - else
              Describe Describe yourself here
          - else
            - if @user.about_me
              = @user.about_me
            - else
              = "#{@user.username} has not filled out their about me section yet"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
.testimonial_box
  - if current_user == @user
    - if @user.about_me
      = best_in_place @user, :about_me, :type => :textarea
    - else
      "Describe yourself here"
  - else
    - if @user.about_me
      = @user.about_me
    - else
    = #{@user.name}
    has not filled out their about me section yet
```

This assumes that `current_user` is available and shows the currently logged in user.

Comment: The last part does not show, it leaves the space empty. ```= "#{@user.name} has not filled out their about me section yet"```. That text should read if the `about_me` attribute is NULL.

Comment: Yes. Corrected the answer. See the last 2 lines.

Comment: I tried that prior to submitting comment and unfortunately it does not work. I had to keep the quotations unless I received a error. I should've noted I was working in SLIM. I updated my question with current code.